# if statements in for loop both executing instead of just one

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

First If statement works just fine, then it goes into the for loop as expected BUT THEN OUT OF NOWHERE, it decides to execute both if statements (which they are contradictory of each other "==" and "!=")..I don't understand :(

```
if($scope.firstinitial==$scope.firstinput&&$scope.secondinitial==$scope.secondinput){
      $scope.initialmatches="MATCHES THE INITIALS";



for (var i=0; i<$scope.discountcodes.length; i++) {
    console.log($scope.discountcodes[i]);


      if($rootScope.discountcodeinput.attempt.toLowerCase()!=$scope.discountcodes[i]){
        $scope.changeBack();//DOES ONLY IF INPUT DOES NOT MATCH DATA

      }
  if($rootScope.discountcodeinput.attempt.toLowerCase()==$scope.discountcodes[i]){
        console.log($scope.discountcodes[i]);//DOES ONLY IF INPUT MATCHES DATA
        $scope.changeBackAgain();
      }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
After bug testing, only the last discount code when matched works correctly...which boggles my mind even further. So when the user types in the discount code which matches the last discount code in the array, then only the first if statement triggers and not the second one. Any ideas?

Comment: So, once the first if has executed, doesn't that make the second if true?

Comment: Both `if` blocks are running on **each** iteration of `i`? Or is each `if` running in a different iteration?

Comment: try replacing the second if with else if

Comment: Near as I can tell, you're calling a function that changes the variables in the $scope, so it's entirely possible both conditions may be valid.

Comment: the function changeBack() and changeBackAgain() simply change the background image...they have nothing to do with discountcodeinput or discountcodes[]... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think whatever is happening inside `$scope.changeBack();` is making the second condition `true`

Answer (score 1):

If `$scope.changeBack();` does something to modify `discountcodes[i]` or `$rootScope.discountcodeinput.attempt` it is possible for the second if statement to execute. What you probably mean to do is:

```
for (var i=0; i<$scope.discountcodes.length; i++) {
    if($rootScope.discountcodeinput.attempt.toLowerCase()!=$scope.discountcodes[i]){
        $scope.changeBack();//DOES ONLY IF INPUT DOES NOT MATCH DATA
    }
    else {
        $scope.changeBackAgain();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but no dice...since I let the user continue inputing until they get a match could there be some sort of caching where the if statement begins from the last place it left off...maybe there is a need for some return; or something

Comment: It sounds like maybe your loop is executing twice. Can you post a working example?

Comment: I can't post my exact code as project is private but I just added an edit that might help you figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Apparently using the == operator can have very unexpected results due to the type-coercion internally, so using === is always the recommended

also add an else statement in there if you don't need both of them executing.

Other than that I would say that something is changing, I would step through it in the debug window and see what the current results are for each variable or print them to the console.

```
if($scope.firstinitial==$scope.firstinput&&$scope.secondinitial==$scope.secondinput){
      $scope.initialmatches="MATCHES THE INITIALS";



for (var i=0; i<$scope.discountcodes.length; i++) {
    console.log($scope.discountcodes[i]);


      if($rootScope.discountcodeinput.attempt.toLowerCase()!==$scope.discountcodes[i]){
        $scope.changeBack();//DOES ONLY IF INPUT DOES NOT MATCH DATA

      }
  else if($rootScope.discountcodeinput.attempt.toLowerCase()===$scope.discountcodes[i]){
        console.log($scope.discountcodes[i]);//DOES ONLY IF INPUT MATCHES DATA
        $scope.changeBackAgain();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what the result of double equals `==` is, `!=` will be the opposite of it. That's not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using the else if statement to run one code then the other

```
    <script>
    if($scope.firstinitial==$scope.firstinput&&$scope.secondinitial==$scope.secondinput){
    $scope.initialmatches="MATCHES THE INITIALS";
        for (var i=0; i<$scope.discountcodes.length; i++) {
        console.log($scope.discountcodes[i]);

        if($rootScope.discountcodeinput.attempt.toLowerCase()==$scope.discountcodes[i]){
            console.log($scope.discountcodes[i]);//DOES ONLY IF INPUT MATCHES DATA
            $scope.changeBackAgain();
        } else if($rootScope.discountcodeinput.attempt.toLowerCase()!=$scope.discountcodes[i]){
            $scope.changeBack();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `($rootScope.discountcodeinput.attempt.toLowerCase()!=$scope.discountcodes[i]` and `($rootScope.discountcodeinput.attempt.toLowerCase()==$scope.discountcodes[i]` can not be true at the same time. So I guess you are doing some magic **inside  `$scope.changeBack()` that changes the value** of either `$rootScope.discountcodeinput.attempt` or `$scope.discountcodes[i]`, so when the second if gets checked, the value has already changed and the condition passes.

I would suggest breaking out of the iteration as soon as you know you are done, by adding a `continue` statement. Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.discountcodes.length; i++) {
  console.log($scope.discountcodes[i]);

  if ($rootScope.discountcodeinput.attempt.toLowerCase() != $scope.discountcodes[i]) {
    $scope.changeBack(); //DOES ONLY IF INPUT DOES NOT MATCH DATA
    continue; // done
  }

  // no need to check again
  console.log($scope.discountcodes[i]); //DOES ONLY IF INPUT MATCHES DATA
  $scope.changeBackAgain();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

Essentially the for loop was going through and checking both if statements with each object, if the first object matched it would trigger the first if statement and not the second. BUT then the for loop would continue and look at the next object in the array and only trigger the second if statement...then it would loop through with the third object in the array and again only trigger the second if statement...so on and so on.

The workaround I came up with was just embedding both into another if statement that checked for a var value of yes

```
if($scope.value=="no")
```

then I placed the not equal if statement `(!=)` first and the equal if statement `(==)` second. Finally, I added in the `(==)` if statement:

```
$scope.value="yes";
```

thus avoiding going through the parent if statement on every loop of the for loop.

Thanks everyone for the help...this was killing me!